# If I am on a 90-day visa waiver and find a possible employer what do I do?

Tags: usa, work, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

My boyfriend is coming to stay with me in the US for 84 days under the visa waiver program, he is looking for a soccer job or employment. If someone finds interest in him and wants him to join their team, how will he need to go about this? Does he need visas, documentation, anything? He is traveling from London, UK.

Comment: Unless he is eligible to work in the US, he's going to have to get a work visa of some kind. Questions about that would probably be better asked on the 'Expatriates' site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about work visas

Answer (score 5):

It is legal to look for work whilst in the US under the Visa Waiver Program, however it is NOT legal to actually work whilst on the WVP.

If he is offered any form of employment within the US he will need to return to his home country and apply for a work visa for the US.  Depending on the specific situation, obtaining such a visa will be somewhere between complicated and impossible.

Comment: ha ha. +1 for nicely explain that _" such a visa will be somewhere between complicated and impossible."_